# nodejs method() Is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

A newbie with NodeJs. I am trying to use async/ series but I got this error:

> task.save is not a function

This is my code

```
async.series([
(cb) => {
            Task
                .findById(id)
                .then((task) => {
                   //do somethink
                    cb(null, task);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    if (err) return res.bad(err);
                });
        },
        (task, cb) => {
           //do somethink
            task.save((err, data) => {
                cb(err, data);
            });
        }
    ], (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.bad(err);
        res.ok(data);
    });
```

Comment: It could really be that "task.save" is not a function. How about console log "task" and see if a function "save" is a method of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async.series` executes all the passed functions in series, *but independent of each other*.

In your case, you have a dependency, namely that the second function depends on the result of the previous function (by means of the `task` variable).

For that, you need to use [`async.waterfall`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall)